# How to check if a zip file is password protected in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) to extract zip files in an iOS application, but I want to know before openning the file if it's password protected or not so that I can pass the password to the UnZipOpenFile function.

Comment: first try opening normally if it does not succeed then try using password by prompting user to enter password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

password of a zip file is not record in header
it is recorded in individual file entries in zip

so you need to check all files in zip

add this function to ZipArchive

```
-(BOOL) UnzipIsEncrypted {

    int ret = unzGoToFirstFile( _unzFile );
    if (ret == UNZ_OK) {
        do {
            ret = unzOpenCurrentFile( _unzFile );
            if( ret!=UNZ_OK ) {
                return NO;
            }
            unz_file_info   fileInfo ={0};
            ret = unzGetCurrentFileInfo(_unzFile, &fileInfo, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);
            if (ret!= UNZ_OK) {
                return NO;
            }
            else if((fileInfo.flag & 1) == 1) {
                return YES;
            }

            unzCloseCurrentFile( _unzFile );
            ret = unzGoToNextFile( _unzFile );
        } while( ret==UNZ_OK && UNZ_OK!=UNZ_END_OF_LIST_OF_FILE );

    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This function is failing even for locked zip. For locked file it returns here if( ret!=UNZ_OK ) .... ANY IDEA?

Answer (score 3):

Acctually i couldn't find function in zipArchive that detects if the file is encrypted so i checked the file header to check if it's password protected or not as stated in the following link:

http://secureartisan.wordpress.com/2008/11/04/analysis-of-encrypted-zip-files/

```
-(BOOL) IsEncrypted:(NSString*)path
{
    NSData* fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSData* generalBitFlag = [fileData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)];
    NSString* genralBitFlgStr = [generalBitFlag description];

    if ([genralBitFlgStr characterAtIndex:2]!='0')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for all

Comment: just one question, if the password is a empty string, this will not work. Is there any way to detect whether the password is empty?

Comment: unfortunately i haven't tried this situation .. Also I've tried my approach and it failed in some cases  as the general bit flag was n't equal to zero although it wasn't password protected.That's why i used IPaPa solution which is marked as answered and it worked.

Comment: this fails if the zip file has all files inside a root folder. Although good for single file zip files

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used ZipArchive myself but by looking at the code it seams possible to first use the `UnzipOpenFile` variant without password argument and try to call `UnzipFileTo`. If it fails you reopen but with a password and call `UnzipFileTo` again. The problem with this is that you will not be able to distinguish between an invalid zip file and using a invalid password.

If you really need to know if the file is encrypted you could probably add the functionally yourself (untested code):

Add this to `unzip.c` in minizip:

```
extern int ZEXPORT unzIsEncrypted (file)
    unzFile file;
{
   return ((unz_s*)file)->encrypted;
}
```

This to `unzip.h`:

```
extern int ZEXPORT unzIsEncrypted OF((unzFile file));
```

This to `ZipArchive.mm`:

```
- (BOOL)ZipIsEncrypted {
    return unzIsEncrypted(_unzFile);
}
```

This to `ZipArchive.h`:

```
- (BOOL)ZipIsEncrypted;
```

And use it after calling `UnzipFileTo`.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing with ZipArchive and I found this!!!!! This is amazing!!!

Comment: unz_s undefined how did you made it working?

Comment: Sorry no idea, has the unz_s struct been renamed? or your adding it to the wrong source file?

Answer (score 1):

i was unzipping more than 50mb Encrypted file so load full file in NSData was problem for me.
so modified answer and
i used this:

```
-(BOOL) IsEncrypted:(NSString*)path

{

    NSInteger chunkSize = 1024     //Read 1KB chunks.
    NSFileHandle *handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
    NSData *fileData = [handle readDataOfLength:chunkSize];
    NSData* generalBitFlag = [fileData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)];
    NSString* genralBitFlgStr = [generalBitFlag description];


    if ([genralBitFlgStr characterAtIndex:2]!='0')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```